# Angular 4 delete tag but not childs

Tags: angular, material-design

I need to do something like this

```
<md-card *ngIf="!asButton">
  <img src="/assets/something.png">
  <span>{{ text }}</span>
</md-card>

<button *ngIf="asButton" md-button>
  <img src="/assets/something.png">
  <span>{{ text }}</span>
</button>
```

But I don't want to repeat all the template, there is a better option to do that? maybe with directives or something like that

Comment: what you mean by "repeat all the template"

Comment: because i need to do that but with multiple components, and some of them are much "longer", so if I need to change something, I need to do it two times

Comment: what you mean? these 2 tags are different?

Comment: You can use directives I guess , check this https://angular.io/api/core/Directive

Comment: what is your exact requirement?

Answer (score 0):

**Add new component file**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-page',
  template: `<img src="/assets/something.png">
             <span>{{ text }}</span>`,
  styleUrls: ['./test-page.component.css']
})
export class TestPageComponent {

    text:any='Title';

  constructor() {
    console.log('test page load....');
   }

}
```

**And put selector in your component file like this**

```
<md-card *ngIf="!asButton">
  <app-test-page></app-test-page>
</md-card>

<button *ngIf="asButton" md-button>
  <app-test-page></app-test-page>
</button>
```